# how to fix cors error occured with node api

Tags: node.js

I already set my header to receive json file but I still having cors error here's my code for app.js

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});
```

Comment: You might want to use the package [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).

Answer (score 1):

Use cors package

Find the package from https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

do **npm i cors --save** to add this dependency to **package.json**

Then require this in server file

**var cors = require('cors')**

To enable cors

**app.use(cors());**

So your code will look like

```
const express = require("express");
var cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.listen(8080, function () {
 console.log('Enable cors in all requests..');
})
```

Using this you can Enable All CORS Requests

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cors` **`npm package`**

**`npm install cors`**

**`app.use(cors())`** this one line takes care of everything

Code Sample:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

[Here is the Cors package documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

Comment: @Azku Izad, any trouble implementing this? pls let me know

Comment: Glad to help you.
You can upvote and accept my answer as it may help someone help in future,